# Where is the operator beginbfchar defined in PDF 1.7? I cannot find it in Annex B (operators)

Tags: pdf

Where is the operator *beginbfchar* defined in PDF 1.7? I cannot find it in Annex B, "Operators in Type 4 Functions?

Answer (score 0):

*beginbfchar* among other operators, is in the PDF 1.7 Standard section 9.7.5.4, "CMap Example and Operator Summary".

*beginbfchar* along with its colleague operators (*endbfchar*, *beginbfrange*, ...) are not in Annex B, alas. (This lack just tripped me up today.)